# How to call a function from a different class

Tags: flutter, function, class

I am trying to call the following hideOverlay function from a separate class

```
  hideOverlay() {
    overlayEntry?.remove();
    overlayEntry = null;

    if (overlayEntry != null) {
      overlayEntry.remove();
      overlayEntry = null;
    }
  }
```

In a separate class, I have imported the file containing the function and attempted to call the file by using.

```
hideOverlay();
```

I am a super newbie please advise what I am doing wrong :-(

Answer (score 1):

Put hideOverlay() as a method in a Class, lets call that class 'FirstClass' and from a separate class call an object of the FirstClass class and call that hideOverlay() method like this.

```
import 'first_class.dart';

class SecondClass {
 FirstClass firstClass;
//call function like this when needed.
 firstClass.hiveOverlay()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Fahmida, seems so simple when you know how!

Comment: yes, but you have to know first